# Dropdown doesnt work when I moved it to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

I have a dropdown which I took from here, https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_custom_select.asp and that works okay in html:

```
<div class="custom-select">
                      <select>
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="0">07.30 - 68.30</option>
                        <option value="0">07.30 - 98.30</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
```

But I need to create this in JavaScript with the click event of button:

```
    function addRow(btn) {
      document.querySelector("#content").insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterbegin",
        `<tr>
        <td>${btn.id}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="custom-select">
            <select>
              <option value="0">IS</option>
              <option value="1">IS 1</option>
              <option value="2">IS 2</option>
            </select>
</div>
        </td>
      </tr>`
      );
    }
```

But when I do it like this, the dropdown doesnt open anymore. So when I write inside of the javascript, I see the element is like in DOM:

```
<td>
            <div class="custom-select">
                <select>
                  <option value="0">IS</option>
                  <option value="1">IS 1</option>
                  <option value="2">IS 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
```

But in html it is like:

```
<div>
                    <div class="custom-select">
                        <select>
                          <option value="0">IS</option>
                          <option value="1">IS 1</option>
                          <option value="2">IS 2</option>
                        </select>
                    <div class="select-selected">IS</div><div class="select-items select-hide"><div>IS 1</div><div>IS 2</div></div></div>
                </div>
```

So I dont know why it doesn add ISIS 1IS 2 automatically.

Do you know why?

Thanks.

Comment: On Safari for Mac things work just fine.

Comment: Please share what the table that you're inserting this row into looks like. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice

Comment: Still have problem?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the `.custom-select` `<div>` tag. Could be the cause of the issue